# Remove subviews with tags safely

Tags: iphone, ios, tags, subviews

This is not a real problem, i want just a clarification.
I'm adding some subviews on a UIButton(each button has a tag), i know that there may be either 4 or 5 subviews.
So, when i want to remove some subviews(specifically the 4th and 5th in this case):

```
int cnt=[[(UIView *)[self.scrollView viewWithTag:index] subviews] count];
  if (cnt==4) {
      [[[(UIView *)[self.scrollView viewWithTag:index] subviews] objectAtIndex:3] removeFromSuperview];
  }
  if (cnt==5) {
      [[[(UIView *)[self.scrollView viewWithTag:index] subviews] objectAtIndex:3] removeFromSuperview];
    //[[[(UIView *)[self.scrollView viewWithTag:index] subviews] objectAtIndex:4] removeFromSuperview]; <-- this crash
      [[[(UIView *)[self.scrollView viewWithTag:index] subviews] objectAtIndex:3] removeFromSuperview];

    }
```

The commented line can not be executed, of course, because there aren't more 5, but 4 subviews.
So I have to remove the view pointing twice on the same index.
I would like to know if it's a safe way to remove them, and i want to be sure that the last view is moved one position lower in the array `[[self.scrollView viewWithTag:index] subviews]`.

Hope it is clear.
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd rather use something like this:

```
for(int i=cnt-1;i>=3;i--)
{
  [[[(UIView *)[self.scrollView viewWithTag:index] subviews] objectAtIndex:i] removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Usually, when removing objects from lists, the safest method is to begin at the end. This way it doesn't even matter if they get reorganized.

Answer (score 8):

If you know the tags of the views that you want to remove then a safer way of doing this is:

```
[[parentView viewWithTag:tag] removeFromSuperview];
```

Here you are asking the child view to remove itself, rather than asking the parent view to remove the child based on some assumed ordering that may be wrong.

Comment: Also, it doesn't matter if there _isn't_ a view with the particular tag, it will just return nil and you can call any method you like on it.

Comment: thanks for the response, i know this, but the child subviews doesn't have a tag, i just know that there may be 4 or 5 subviews.

Comment: Accessing your child views by some assumed order sounds really fragile to me. Tag them or have some other way of identifying them (e.g. keep references to them in instance variables or in a dictionary)

Comment: ok this is the point that i'm trying to understand..do you think that the order of that array could change? I don't know in which way the system operates on that array.

Comment: The order of the array is the stacking or z-order of the subviews i.e. views at the end of the array will visually cover views at the start of the array if they overlap.

Comment: "Fragile" doesn't mean that your code will stop working in the middle of a run because the array spontaneously changes order. It means that as you change your code in the future, you might add elements earlier in the array, or change their order. If you forget to also update the above code, then it will be broken. As an analogy, a fragile package in a box doesn't break while sitting on the warehouse floor, but it can break while the movers are moving it if they aren't careful.

Comment: @morningstar Exactly! Well put.